# Error: write after end

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm receiving the following error when using the drive.files.update method of the google-api-nodejs-client

```
Error: write after end
at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:422:15)
at Request.write (/Users/user/GitHub/project/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1362:25)
at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:528:20)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at onread (fs.js:1832:12)
at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:614:17)
```

I get this when simply using `fs.createReadStream()`

```
global.drive.files.update({
    fileId: 'IHU0...',
    media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream('file.js')
    },
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(`Error occurred: ${err.stack}`);
    }
    console.log(`UPDATED, response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
});
```

Comment: I got the same issue, did you find a solution ?